# Can I put an executable in the user's PATH without admin-level privileges?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'd like to add Windows support to a language version manager I use.

In its current macOS-and-Linux-only form, the manager downloads a few key language binaries/executables (compiler, linter, etc) to its own folder, with a subfolder for each version (manager/1.1/, manager/1.2/, and so on). When you run `manager use 1.1`  or `manager use 1.2`, it symlinks `/usr/local/bin/language` to the relevant folder.

Windows doesn't let you symlink without administrator privileges. Fair enough, I figure, I'll just copy the binaries directly. And that's where I'm at now: I'd like to copy these binaries into some equivalent of `/usr/local/bin`, somewhere user-accessible on the PATH. But my knowledge of Windows isn't deep enough to know whether this is possible and my googling hasn't turned up anything either. The PATH variable sharing a name with a fundamental filesystem feature kind of muddies searches up.

Big thanks to anyone who can offer me a tip here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to set the `PATH` on Windows. The easiest ones are explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/1305969).

- Add the path to *My Computer->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables->Path*
- Use `set  PATH="%PATH%;C:\NewPath"` setting the `PATH` for this session
- Use `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\NewPath"` setting the `PATH` for all sessions of this user in the future
- Use `setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\NewPath"` setting the `PATH` for all sessions of all users machine-wide in the future
- Modifiy the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path` and add `C:\NewPath`
- Use the [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx) .NET Windows Method to modify the registry key
- Use [PowerShell to modify it permanently](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/23/use-powershell-to-modify-your-environmental-path/)

Disclaimer: I haven't tested which of these approaches require admin priviledges.